# Make a signed query with Amazon API MWS

Tags: php, api, amazon-mws

I'm trying to make a signed request for Seller Amazon Web Services (MWS).
I'm using a script from here:
[Converting amazon MWS scratchpad queries to API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694376/converting-amazon-mws-scratchpad-queries-to-api-calls)

But I don't know why I've got an error:
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

So here is my script:

```
define ("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "xxxxx");
define ("MERCHANT_ID", "xxxxx");
define ("MARKETPLACE_ID", "xxxxx");
define ("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","xxxxx");

$base_url = "https://mws.amazonservices.fr/Products/2011-10-01";
$method = "POST";
$host = "mws.amazonservices.fr";
$uri = "/Products/2011-10-01";

function amazon_xml($searchTerm) {

$params = array(
'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
'Action' => "GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU",
'SellerId' => MERCHANT_ID,
'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
'SignatureVersion' => "2",
'Timestamp'=> date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
'Version'=> "2011-10-01",
'MarketplaceId' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
'Query' => $searchTerm,
'ItemCondition'=> "New",
'ExcludeMe' => "false");


// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
$url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$url_string = str_replace("%7E", "~", implode("&", $url_parts));
$string_to_sign = "POST\nmws.amazonservices.fr\n/Products/2011-10-01\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.fr/Products/2011-10-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

return ($parsed_xml);
}
```

I don't understand what's going wrong 
If someone could help....

Thanks in advance !

Comment: For the timestamp, I think you have to use `gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z')`

Answer (score 2):

You got an issue when you are signing the string..try this

```
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Products/2011-10-01\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
```

its working for me...Hopes this helps

Comment: The 'TRUE' at the end of hash_hmac fixed a problem that has been bugging me for days. Just wanted to highlight that this is could be the key to a lot of people's problems. Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times. Amazon's documentation is terrible on this.

Comment: Hi, I am new to Amazon MWS. I am able to get both the Scratchpad (https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/) and the above code by @zaffar-saffee to work for the call `GetServiceStatus`. However, I think this call does not require additional auth.

I cannot get any other calls to work. I am getting the error AccessDenied.

This is an internal app so I do not want to / have not applied for developer status nor do I want to use the new SP-API. According to all of the docs I've read, I shouldn't need either for an internal app, correct? What am I doing wrong or needing further access grants?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when using cURL you set the method to "GET", in the above example change to

$method = "GET";

and it should work.